# Can't decrypt immediately after encryption

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I want to use GPG to create an encyrpted backup. I am testing the encryption before I use it and it's not working like I expect.  I am using this script to test it:

```
gpg --gen-key

gpg --encrypt $0
gpg --decrypt $0.gpg
```

I am specifying myself (i.e. the key I generated using `--gen-key`) as the recipient.  However, when I enter the passphrase I used for it, it gives me the error, `Invalid passphrase; please try again`.

How can it be invalid?  I created it seconds ago.

Comment: Sounds like another key is used for encryption. Try specifying the recipient using `--recipient`.

Comment: verify that is the right password>
use gpg --list-keys
gpg --edit-key _pubkeyfromabove_ 
now type passwd
enter passphrase.
If it allows you past this then something else is wrong.

Comment: I was selecting keys by e-mail address and I had multiple keys with the same address.  When I selected by hex ID it worked properly.